# How I mount a writeable sparsebundle as writeable?

Tags: macos, permissions, file-permissions, dmg-image, sparsebundle

I created a sparsebundle with my admin user.

Mounted it, added files to it, worked a bit, etc...

Created another user.

Booted as the other user, and couldn't write to the sparsebundle, then I went back to admin... and can't write there either. No matter what I do it mounts as read-only. Despite the fact until I created the other user it was write-able normally.

How I force it to be write-able?